# Detecting Synonymous Links

Tags: javascript, html, url, hyperlink

I have a database of link URLs from a recent web crawl.
I am working on a visualization/path finding suite and ran into a slight problem with my dataset.

Since the site I crawled was written by humans the link styles and syntaxes vary, i.e. a link to "http://home.page" instead of "http://home.page/" or even "http://home.page/index.html".

Obviously these URLs all refer to the same page, but since their URLs aren't identical they are stored as distinct entries in my database.

This makes path finding between pages difficult as no matter which style you choose only a fraction of the actually links are detected.

**I was wondering if there is anyway to either generate all possible "synonym" links for a given url, or more likely to detect whether the two links are synonymous (point to the same page), assuming no custom routing rules have been applied.**

I'm using the M.E.A.N. stack and d3.js for visualization so JavaScript is the language of choice.

To be clear I am not really asking for critique on the way I have setup my database (though advice is always welcome), and am not really interested in re-running a crawl.

I am wondering if there is an existing heuristic that could identify whether two URLs are likely synonymous based on web development convention, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://home.page` and `http://home.page/` are equivalent, as HTTP requires a resource path of some kind, so `/` is sent by the browser.

However, `http://home.page/` and `http://home.page/index.html` are **not** necessarily equivalent, and unless there is a redirect from one to the other you have no way of knowing what the rewrite rules are on the server.

The only thing you can do here is compare content to see if it is identical.  However, even then there can be differences as pages are often generated dynamically.  (A good example of a trivial difference is when some developers put a page generation time in the footer.  This means that the results for different URLs are different, even if they are fundamentally the same from a content perspective.)

I should also note that many pages have a canonical URL specified in their meta tags.  This is what search engines use to determine the normal URL for a page.  There is no guarantee however that this will be present or correct.